# Is it possible to make an all natural smoke detector from Brazil nuts?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

After reading about Brazil nuts, I discovered they have very high levels of radiation due to trace amounts of Ra-226 and Ra-228 and their decay products. A kilogram of the nut, for instance, gives a reading between 40 and 2660 becquerels.

Ionizing smoke detectors use a strong alpha-emitter to ionize air molecules between two plates. When smoke particulates in the air obstruct the flow of ions between the plates an alarm is triggered. Radium-226 was the first radioactive source in smoke detectors before it was switched over to Americium-241.

Given that today's smoke detectors operate on 0.05 µCi or 1850 Bq of radiation, is it possible to build a smoke detector apparatus using Brazil nuts as a radiation source?

**Citations:**

[Smoke detectors](https://www.orau.org/health-physics-museum/collection/consumer/miscellaneous/smoke-detector.html#:%7E:text=Radium%2D226%20(radium%20sulfate),they%20switched%20to%20Am%2D241.)

[Brazil nuts](https://www.orau.org/health-physics-museum/collection/consumer/food/brazil-nuts.html)

Comment: This sounds like something straight out of [What If?](https://what-if.xkcd.com/)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Smoke detector in the hallway outside my bedroom door—purchased new just a year ago—says it contains 0.9 µCi of 241-Am. That's 90 times what you said for "today's smoke detectors." If we go with your highest estimate, 2660 Bq per kg of nut meat, we're going to need 12.5 kg of nut meat to get as much radioactivity as my smoke detector needs.

But here's the thing. A smoke detector depends on *alpha* particles to ionize the air in the chamber, and no alpha particles can escape from the interior of a mass of nut meat. You need the radioactive source to be concentrated in a thin film.

By the time you have processed the 12.5 kg of nut meat to sufficiently concentrate the radium for the application, can you honestly call it "all natural" at that point?

Comment: All naturally sourced?

Comment: @user148298, If it doesn't say "certified organic," then it's just a bunch of marketing hype. "Mmmm! Certified Organic radium."

Comment: Geez!  Some folks are just looking to close questions for the most trivial reasons. Please vote to reopen it.

Comment: Good question, excellent answer - voting to reopen.

Comment: @user148298 I would say that almost all Radium is "naturally sourced", but typically not from trees. The technical term is even *[Naturally occurring radioactive material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturally_occurring_radioactive_material).*

Comment: I hope we don't see YouTube videos: "Easy DIY smoke smoke detector made from brazil nuts!"

Comment: ‘nut meat’ sounds inappropriate

Comment: @sato, In Old English, "mete" was the word for _all_ kinds of food, not just animal muscle tissue. Today, "meat" still is used to distinguish the edible parts of some things—especially, of nuts, and also of course, animals—from their inedible parts. (https://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meat, definition 1b.) This also explains the occasional metaphorical use of the word, such as when somebody talks about "the _meat_ of the problem."